# How much does a steel spring wire bend due to it's own weight?

Tags: material-science

I'm working on an art project and I need to know how much a steel spring wire bends dependent on it's diameter. It's point of support is in the middle and it's lengths is `1.20m`. How much lower are the end points in relation to the center?

```
1. A diameter of 1.20mm
2. A diameter of 1.50mm
```

**Edit:**

I've found the following values for spring steel: $p = 7800 kg/m^3$, $E = 2.1×10^{11} N/m^2$. But [I've trouble reproducing your results](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%5Cfrac%7B5%2a%28120cm%29%5E4+%2a+%288000+kg%2Fm%5E3%29+%2a+%289.807+m%2Fs%5E2%29+%7D%7B12+%2a+%282.0%C3%9710%5E11+N%2Fm%5E2%29+%2a+%281.5mm%29%5E2%7D), I'm not sure if I assembled you equation right.

**Edit**
[Corrected formula in W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%5Cfrac%7B5%2a%2860cm%29%5E4+%2a+%287800+kg%2Fm%5E3%29+%2a+%289.807+m%2Fs%5E2%29+%7D%7B12+%2a+%282.1%C3%9710%5E11+N%2Fm%5E2%29+%2a+%281.3mm%2F2%29%5E2%7D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach to this question would be with [Euler-Bernoulli beam theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_equation), which in your case simply says that the beam's vertical deflection $z(x)$ satisfies the equation 
$$EI \frac{d^4 z}{dx^4}= \lambda g$$
where $\lambda$ is the linear density of the wire, $E$ is the wire's Young Modulus, and $I$ is the second moment of area. For a circular wire of radius $R$, you have $I=\frac{\pi}{2}R^4$ and $\lambda = \pi R^2 \rho$ where $\rho$ is the volume density. Plugging that to the equation yields
$$\frac{E R^2}{2 \rho g}\frac{d^4 z}{dx^4}= 1 $$

Solving this equation with the right boundary conditions gives

$$z(x)=\frac{\rho g}{12 E R^2}x^2\left(x^2-6 L^2 \right) $$

and therefore the deflection at $x=L$ is $$z(x=\pm L)=-\frac{5 L^4 \rho g}{12 E R^2}$$
I don't know what do you mean by tensile strength, but I suspect that it is not enough in order to determine $E$. Instead, if you take $E=200\times 10^9 N/m^2$ from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus) and $\rho=8000 kg/m^3$ ([also from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel#Material_properties)) and plug that all in, you'll have ~1m for the 1.20mm thick wire and 60cm for the 1.50mm thick wire.

Edit: I forgot to carry $g$ in my answer, and therefore my previous answer was wrong by a factor of $g$. I now updated the values, which are large compared to the length of the wire. ***This makes the beam-equation inaccurate***, and one should solve the problem without assuming small deflections. It is possible, and my (new) answer gives a fair estimation of the result.

Comment: 60 cm seems be be a lot for a [spring steel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_steel). It has probably a different tensile modulus than ordinary steel?

Comment: Maybe. Note also that using a wire of double diameter will decrease the deflection by a factor of 4, so that might also bbe a solution.

Comment: Oh, and another thing - I took $L$ to be the length from the point of support to the end, but re-reading you question makes me think that $L$ is total length. If that is the case, you should divide all my answers by $2^4$ to get 5.9cm and 3.8cm.

Comment: You used diameter or 1.3 mm in your formula. Here you give 1.2mm or 1.5mm.

Comment: This solution looks **totally wrong** because the Euler-Bernoulli beam theory is related to deflection due to bending while in a spring we have deflection due to torsion.

Comment: @user29346 Spring wire, not spring. And not all springs deflect due to torsion - torsion springs undergo bending stress